# Prevent dropped frames which capturing video in DirectShow

Tags: c#, directshow, video-capture, directshow.net

I've written a relatively straightforward code in C# (and DirectShow.net) in order to capture video from a camera into a file. My problem is that the graph is dropping too many frames while recording. I don't think that the problem is hardware related, as it is not a very demanding video (640x480 at 25fps), and I have a fairly strong computer. 
Any thoughts on best practices to prevent frame drops?

**EDIT**:

Here is my code:

```
Graph = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();

Source = CreateFilter(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice, SelectedDevice);
hr = Graph.AddFilter(Source, "Source");
TestForError("Error while adding source filter", hr);

Builder = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
hr = Builder.SetFiltergraph(Graph);
TestForError("Error setting preview graph", hr);

Guid guid = DirectShowLib.MediaSubType.Avi;
hr = Builder.SetOutputFileName(guid, filename, out AVIMux, out FileWriter);
TestForError("Error setting capture graph", hr);

// Set VMR
VMR = (IBaseFilter)new VideoMixingRenderer9();
hr = Graph.AddFilter(VMR, "Renderer");
TestForError("Error creating preview subgraph", hr);
ConfigureWindowlessMode();

// Render Capture & Preview streams
hr = Builder.RenderStream(PinCategory.Preview, MediaType.Video, Source, null, VMR);
TestForError("Preview stream rendering error", hr);

hr = Builder.RenderStream(PinCategory.Capture, MediaType.Video, Source, null, AVIMux);
TestForError("Capture stream rendering error", hr);

//
Control = (IMediaControl)Graph;
mediaEventEx = (IMediaEventEx)Graph;
hr = mediaEventEx.SetNotifyWindow(Handle, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, IntPtr.Zero);
TestForError("Error setting notifications", hr);

Control.Run();
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  Frames should not be dropped - you need to explain more about HOW you are doing it, give some code samples, etc.  What is your video input?  USB?

Comment: To add to Daniel's above - you need to start with checking the filter graph topology you are having. And it's worth sharing it as well, so that others get an idea what exactly is going on.

Comment: I've added the code that I'm using. @daniel-mosmondor The video input is either a USB webcam (which I use for testing), or an analog frame-grabber

Comment: I had a hunch that you might be using webcam.  There is one thing with webcam - auto-exposure.  Make sure that it isn't affecting you - in low light situations your frame rate will drop and you won't be able to do anything about it.  Some webcams even don't allow forcing constant exposure time to ensure proper frame flow.